# GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column in Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some trouble with this query displaying and the GROUP BY query. I keep on getting the same error no matter what I do with the GROUP BY. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Currently getting this error:**

**Error:** Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'myData.stateName' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

**Here is my sql:**

```
SELECT 
  stateAbv,
  stateName,
  '' AS cityName,
  count(*) AS state_count 
from
  myData 
GROUP BY stateAbv 
union
SELECT 
  stateAbv,
  stateName,
  city AS cityName,
  COUNT(*) AS city_count 
FROM
  myData 
GROUP BY stateAbv,
  city 
ORDER BY stateAbv,
  cityName
```

Comment: `GROUP BY stateAbv, stateName`

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting the error `GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'myData.stateName'` because the column `stateName` is not in the group by clause, just as it says. So it is saying that you are grouping some rows together and when the query tries to group the `stateName` column, it could having different values within the rows being grouped. The query does not know which one is the right value to show in the grouped row. You need to provide a way to tell the query which value is the right value to keep in grouped row. Say you have a number column, and in the rows you are grouping together has the values `1,2,3 and 4`. You can say i want the highest number from those groups of numbers and do this by `MAX(column_name)` and the grouped row will show `4`.

In your query, if all the values in `stateName` are the same in the rows being grouped, just add the `stateName` in your group by clause.